# Cannot convert from base to generic T

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I need to convert List<Base> objects to a List<T> objects, where T is one of the types that derivate from Base, I know that for sure. But the compiler says:

"Cannot convert from 'Base' to 'T'"

Some code:

```
var rObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

List<T> list = new List<T>();

var ent = rObj.Entities; // Entities is List<Base>

foreach (var i in ent)
    list.Add(i); // here I know that each i is a Base descendent, but the compiler reclams
```

How can I get this? How can I recover derived instances from List, since I only have T information at this runtime moment?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to post more code.  What is T and RootObject ?

Comment: If you have T restricted to Base (like Mick said we need to see the definition of T), you can write `foreach (var i ent.Cast<T>())`. Just adding `i` doesn’t work because if it would you could add a Dog to a list of Cats just because they have the same base class Animal, which wouldn’t make sense. With the cast you are giving a guarantee that you only add Cat objects.

Comment: That is it! Thanks, @ckuri, it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition, `List<Base>`, does not indicate that any of the items in the list are derived from `Base`. The only thing the list enforces is that its items are `Base` or its derived classes. It doesn't enforce that any item is an inherited class or that it is any specific inherited class. (You know what type the list contains, but the compiler doesn't.)

You can do this:

```
listOfT.AddRange(listOfBase.OfType<T>());
```

That will add whichever items are of type `T` to the `List<T>`.

If you're really certain that every item in the list can be cast to `T` then you could do

```
listOfT.AddRange(listOfBase.Cast<T>());
```